# Add TRUNCATE TABLE command in mysqldump before CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql

I need some help, I have this command:

```
mysqldump -u myusername -pmypassword --skip-add-drop-table --no-data --single-transaction database_name | sed 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' > db.sql
```

that can add `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in my `mysqldump`, but I also want to add `TRUNCATE TABLE` command before the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` command, how should I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? 
`ignore-table` seems like it could be a more straightforward approach? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table

Comment: I'm trying to import data without the structure. Quite obvious.

Answer (score 12):

Just add a little more to your regex in sed:

```
mysqldump -u myusername -pmypassword --skip-add-drop-table --no-data --single-transaction database_name | sed -r 's/CREATE TABLE (`[^`]+`)/TRUNCATE TABLE \1; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \1/g' > db.sql
```